# Extracting full image url from source code that starts with url(.../image/../123.jpg)

Tags: html, css, image, extract

I am trying to find out full urls of number of image files from a source code,
But it does not show its full paths.

For example, it shows:

> < tg bgcolor="#FFFFFF" sytle='background-repeat:no-repeat:background-position:right bottom;background-image: url('../img/image_area/123.gif) >

similarly,

> < table width="60" background="../img/print123.gif" >

I tried using original url and mix&paste /img/print123.gif but it did not work.

Many thanks in advace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not, because the paths have been specified relative to the css file.

So you will have to get the url of the css file, go one folder up and then add /img/print123.gif to the url.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to extract url of that css file then?

Comment: It should be there in the souce of the page

Comment: hmm no luck here.. 
only  full url I can find is one "<img src " and thats it.

Comment: Can you share the link of the page?

Comment: I would like to, but this page is an intranet page. I am using a separate PC to write this comment. Its bit long to copy it via hand too :P. This page does not have <link rel=  in the source code, So no css url. I tried going other page of this and tried looking at the source code but only the main page gives <link rel= "../css/css/123.css"/> and thats it. Oh well looks like my attempt to prank has failed :D

Comment: Oh nevermind! pressing F12 devloper console gave it right away! so the prank may continue..